# How to make the whole line change color in Eclipse when I toggle a breakpoint?

Tags: java, eclipse

This will help debugging, anyone knows how?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

seems to be possible, go to

```
Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations
```

here you will see list of 'annotations types', choose 'breakpoints'. Then on the right side you see 'Show in', check there 'Text as' and select 'Highlighted', below you can set background color.

Screenshot to make it more obvious:

[image]